# Cufon Text Disappear in jcarousel

Tags: jcarousel, cufon

Iam implementing cufon on infinite carousel. The problem is that when carousel  dynamically generates next loop cufon dont shows there in that loop. Is there any fix? and Is there any way to implement cufon on dynamically generated text?

Here is the Demo link

http://hashmatabbas.zxq.net/demo/

click on right button and after two scrolls the cufon disappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Cufon.replace instead Cufon.refresh

```
jQuery(".jcarousel-next, .jcarousel-prev").click(function() {
      Cufon.replace(".box_desc h3"); 
})
```

Comment: It's not working in Internet Explorer 8 - i receive cufon text under regular fonts - http://floomby.ru/content/hzjMHkhkOH like at this example.

May anybody have same problem and find decision?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the jquery.jcarousel.js and add

```
Cufon.refresh(".your class here");
```

within the next & previous functions.

So for example, currently on 06/28/11 I'm using Version: 0.2.8 from http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ the code you want to modify starts on line 455, see sample below:

```
/**
* Moves the carousel forwards.
*
* @method next
* @return undefined
*/
next: function() {
if (this.tail !== null && !this.inTail) {
this.scrollTail(false);
} else {
this.scroll(((this.options.wrap == 'both' || this.options.wrap == 'last') && this.options.size !== null && this.last == this.options.size) ? 1 : this.first + this.options.scroll);
Cufon.refresh(".your class here");
}
},

/**
* Moves the carousel backwards.
*
* @method prev
* @return undefined
*/
prev: function() {
if (this.tail !== null && this.inTail) {
this.scrollTail(true);
} else {
this.scroll(((this.options.wrap == 'both' || this.options.wrap == 'first') && this.options.size !== null && this.first == 1) ? this.options.size : this.first - this.options.scroll);
Cufon.refresh(".your class here");
}
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger `Cufon.refresh();` like so:

```
jQuery(".jcarousel-next, .jcarousel-prev").click(function() {
      Cufon.refresh(".box_desc h3"); 
})
```